# Disable aggressive overloading in ProGuard for Android

Tags: java, android, overloading, proguard

In order to ease users' stacktraces analysis, I'd like to disable "aggressive overloading" when ProGuard is obfuscating my Android app. In my obfuscated APK, I often have classes containing several methods/fields named `a()` in the same class, which is quite difficult to analyze a stacktrace, since it doesn't include method parameters or line number.

According to the [ProGuard documentation](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#overloadaggressively), using option `-overloadaggressively` forces this overloading. The problem is that ProGuard seems to use this option when obfuscating my app even if my ProGuard configuration file doesn't contain this option:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

How can I disable this aggressive overloading?

My target is Android 3.2 / API level 13.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/413/ ?

Comment: Thanks, it works (using `-useuniqueclassmembernames` option instead). Feel free to post this in an answer to win some points ;)

Comment: If you post an answer and explain how you fixed it would be better than an answer with only a link :)

Comment: Done. I will accept my own answer tomorrow (I'm not allowed to do it now)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The option `-overloadaggressively` only pertains to the *return types* of methods.

- The Java language already allows ordinary overloading, where different methods can have the same name, as long as they have different argument types.
- Java bytecode additionally allows "aggressive" overloading, where different methods can have the same name, as long as they have different argument/return types.

As a result, even `-useuniqueclassmembernames` can't guarantee unique names, since the names may be overloaded to start with. To get unambiguous stack traces, you should preserve line numbers:

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-renamesourcefileattribute ''
```

See the ProGuard manual > Examples > Producing useful stack traces.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I understand now. For now, `-useuniqueclassmembernames` seems to work great (I already found your examples to produce useful stack traces, it's now perfect for debugging!). 
Maybe the description of `-overloadaggressively` could contain what you explained here. I'm not an expert but I didn't understand this when I first read the documentation.
Anyway, great tool you've made, thanks for this hard work!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Marco Acierno, I found that using the option `-useuniqueclassmembernames` instead of trying to remove option `-overloadaggressively` works (no more aggressive overloading). It seems that the option `-overloadaggressively` was not designed to perform this... Quite strange but it works.

More information here: http://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/413/